# Adding a message box over paint panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, paint

I have this code below, this class extends JPanel and gets some parameters from its constructor and draws lines over a picture i uploaded.

```
 @Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(4f);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth() * 3 / 5,image.getHeight() * 3 / 5,this);
    g2d.setStroke(stroke);

    for (int i=0; i<pathler.size(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<pathler.get(i).size() - 1; j++) {
            g2d.drawLine(pathler.get(i).get(j).getX(),pathler.get(i).get(j).getY(),pathler.get(i).get(j+1).getX(),pathler.get(i).get(j+1).getY());
        }

    }
    for (int i=0; i<lastpath.size() - 1; i++){
        g2d.drawLine(lastpath.get(i).getX(),lastpath.get(i).getY(),lastpath.get(i+1).getX(),lastpath.get(i+1).getY());
    }


}
```

And i use this code below to call it on main;

```
    Main jf = new Main("App");
    jf.setSize(1500,800);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Gui gui = new Gui(nodes,path,path3);
    jf.add(gui);
    jf.setVisible(true);
```

And all i want is a small box over that picture when i run this, it will show my path strings( i will write them, the content of the box isn't issue ) and user can press OK or top right of the box to close it, it s not problem to make it draggable or not. I am foreign to layouts,panels etc so i can't understand. Actually it s just a simple box like when you get an error message on computer (or panel or message box, idk how to call it exactly). I need help for this.

Comment: 1) Custom painting should be done by overriding `paintComponent(...)`, not paint(). 2) I would guess you are looking for a `JOptionPane`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Use a JOptionPane with the showMessageDialog() method, for example: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My Message text here", "My Title Here", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

Comment: Thank you i am using JOptionPane in main right now but my Jframe (paint) is being opened after i press OK in the message dialog, but i want the box and jframe to open in same time and i can see them both on screen, can you help me for this ?

Comment: oh ok it s fixed when i change the first parameter to my jframe object instead of null.

Comment: You can add `JtextField` or any other component the `JPanel`.